# Maps and records equality in Clojure

Tags: dictionary, clojure, record, equality

I found the behavior of Clojure confusing regarding equality between maps and records. In this first example, we have two different types which are structurally equal. The equality = function returns true:

```
user> (defn make-one-map
         []
       {:a "a" :b "b"})
#'user/make-one-map
user> (def m1 (make-one-map))
#'user/m1
user> m1
{:a "a", :b "b"}
user> (def m2 {:a "a" :b "b"})
#'user/m2
user> m2
{:a "a", :b "b"}
user> (= m1 m2)
true
user> (type m1)
clojure.lang.PersistentArrayMap
user> (type m2)
clojure.lang.PersistentHashMap
```

In the second example we have a hashmap and a record which are structurally equivalent but the = function returns false:

```
user> (defrecord Titi [a b])
user.Titi
user> (def titi (Titi. 1 2))
#'user/titi
user> titi
#user.Titi{:a 1, :b 2}
user> (= titi {:a 1 :b 2})
false
```

Why are the differences? I'm using Clojure 1.3 and I found them really confusing.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From the docstring for `defrecord`:

> In addition, defrecord will define type-and-value-based =, and will
>   defined Java .hashCode and .equals consistent with the contract for
>   java.util.Map.

So, when using `=`, type is taken into account. You could use `.equals` instead:

```
user> (.equals titi {:a 1 :b 2})
true
```

Comment: Why are the instances of PersistentArrayMap and PersistentHashMap equal with = then since the type function indicates they are not the same type?

Comment: The "type-and-value-based =" promise is stated in `defrecord`'s docstring and applies to records. Regular maps, on the other hand, are supposed to participate in a value-based = scheme, and they do, to the point that `(= (hash-map :foo 1 :bar 2) (sorted-map :foo 1 :bar 2))` and `(= (java.util.HashMap. {:foo 1 :bar 2}) {:foo 1 :bar 2})` are both `true`.

Answer (score 8):

a `PersistentArrayMap` and a `PersistentHashMap` are conceptually the same - as the ArrayMap grows, it will automatically get converted to a HashMap for performance reasons.  User-level code should generally not try to distinguish between the two.

A `defrecord` datatype, on the other hand, is not the same as one of the other maps.  It is a separate type that may implement entirely different interfaces and should not be automatically replaced by some other form of map.  It is not conceptually equal to a normal map, so `=` returns false.